# Apache url configuration

Tags: php, apache, url, configuration, debian

I have an Apache server where the urls are shown as that: `website.com/folder/folder/main.html`.

There is any Apache configuration to hide the full path? Like StackOverflow, they never show the full path and the document id.

Like: `website.com/folder/`.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: those things are done by modyfying `.htaccess file`

Comment: Not necessarily modifying an `.htaccess` file, but yes, you will need to change Apache's configuration. See `mod_rewrite` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Nevertheless, you may want to ask this question in Server Fault.